# $f=\sum f_ix^i$, where $f_i=\int_0^1\partial_if(tu)dt$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}^m\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$-function vanishing at $0$. Define functions $f_i(u)=\int_0^1\partial_if(tu)dt$ on $\mathbb{R}^m$. Denote by $x^i\colon\mathbb{R}^m\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ the coordinate functions. In my lecture notes, it is remarked that $f=\sum f_ix^i$. Perhaps this is trivial, but I don't see why it holds. Can somebody give a detailed explanation to me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have that for $x\in\mathbb R^n$:

$$f(x)=\int_0^1\frac{d}{dt}f(tx)dt$$

then by using chain-rule we have:

$$\frac{d}{dt}f(tx)=\sum_i\partial_i f(tu)\frac{d}{dt}(tx_i)=\sum_i\partial_i f(tu)x_i$$

therefore:

$$f(x)=\int_0^1\sum_i\partial_i f(tu)x_i=\sum_ix_i\int_0^1\partial_i f(tx)=\sum_i x_if_i(x)$$

which is what you want